# bad request when open php folder on apache

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws

I'm working on ec2 ubuntu instance. I've installed apache and php56 on it but when I try to access a folder like this: http://domain/foldername, I get bad request.

[image: Bad Request]

How to solve this problem?

**Update:**

That's the bad request from log file

```
 [core:error] [pid 3689] [client 154.238.227.62:57401] AH00126: Invalid URI in request GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1, referer: http://domain/foldername/
```

Comment: Check your logs and tells us what type of bad request is being sent!

Comment: I've updated the question

Comment: An requested icon image file can't be found! And it's not an Ubuntu question!